# CellStatistics is not defined error

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, nameerror

Code :

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> ras1 = arcpy.Raster(r'D:\IMD\test_converted1961.img')
>>> ras2 = arcpy.Raster(r'D:\IMD\test_converted1961_fliped_ud1.img')
>>> result = CellStatistics([ras1,ras2], "RANGE", "NODATA")
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'CellStatistics' is not defined
>>>
```

I have refered to the example in the tool help

Answer (score 3):

In the examples posted for [Cell Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm) the `import` statement used is different to yours.

There they use:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
```

which means `CellStatistics()` will be recognized as a function.

You have used simply:

```
import arcpy
```

so you will need to fully describe where in ArcPy to find that function:

```
result = arcpy.sa.CellStatistics([ras1,ras2], "RANGE", "NODATA")
```

Answer (score 1):

For CellStatistics you need Saptial analyst license, I guess you don't have it checked out, so the tool is not available to you. You should check it out first like:

```
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
```

and after that put your:

```
result = CellStatistics([ras1,ras2], "RANGE", "NODATA")...
```

You can also chcek it by desktop client and it should work as well.

Comment: I had the licence the error was due to not importing all the files in arcpy.sa library